# how to structure large table and its transactions in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, mariadb

I have two big tables for example:

**'tbl_items'** and **'tbl_items_transactions'**

First table keeping some items metadata which may have 20 (varchar) columns with millions rows... and second table keeping each transaction of first table.

for example if a user insert new record to `tbl_items` then automatically a new record will be adding to `tbl_items_transactions` with same data plus `date`, `username` and `transaction type` to keep each row history.

so in the above scenario two tables have same columns but `tbl_items_transactions` have **3** extra columns `date`, `username`, `transaction_type` to keep each `tbl_items` history

now assume we have 1000 users that wants to Insert, Update, Delete `tbl_items` records with a web application. so these two tables scale very soon (maybe billion rows in `tbl_items_transactions`)

I have tried MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL... they are very good but when table scale and millions rows inserted they are slow when run some select queries on `tbl_items_transactions`... but sometimes PostgreSQL is faster than MySQL or MariaDB

now I think I'm doing wrong things... If you was me... do you use MariaDB or PostgreSQL or somthing like that and structure your database like what I did?

Comment: Not enough info.  Let's see the "slow" select queries.  And let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It could be an indexing problem, it could be ...

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is wrong.

You should not duplicate the columns from `tbl_items` in `tbl_items_transactions`, rather you should have a foreign key in the latter table pointing to the former.

That way data integrity is preserved, and `tbl_items_transactions` will be much smaller. This technique is called *normalization*.

To speed up queries when the table get large, define *indexes* on them that match the `WHERE` and `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz Albe, but all columns are in plain text and have different values and different things and we don't have duplicate values on each columns. so I can't split my table to other tables and normalize it :(

Comment: and I want to keep history of `tbl_items` data in other table called `tbl_items_transactions` so users can see each columns value at different date and time intervals, for example user change a column value but manager check it and see the value is incorrect and wants to see what was the column value before user change it

Comment: Just avoid redundancy as much as you can. Keep the history in a different table.